# TextMate YAML bundle: Is there one that can display a list of symbols (Go To Symbol dialog, Cmd-Shift-T)?

Tags: bundle, yaml, textmate

I'm working a lot with Rails I18n `.yml` files lately, and I find them rather tedious to navigate when they are deeply nested. E.g. when I have to add a translation for "en.this.is.some.deeply.nested.value" and I don't have any idea whether the according structure already exists (and to which level), I have to do a lot of manual browsing and searching. I'm heavily missing a working "Go To Symbol" dialog (`Cmd-Shift-T`) which is available for many other file types, but not for yml (it's just empty). So maybe there is an YML bundle which supports this? I have already updated my bundle using https://github.com/textmate/yaml.tmbundle, but this doesn't have this feature.

Comment: I share your pain, every day and just now, dealing with an almost 4000 line YAML file, was my breaking point...which is how I ended up here looking for a solution.  Frankly, I'm about ready to hack it in to the bundle myself.  If I do, I'll let you know.

Comment: This would be great. It's really annoying that there's not useful YAML editor out there...